# variable or field declared void Error

Tags: c++, compilation-errors, functions, header

For a larger sketch, I have separated a chunk of code in a separate .cpp file

```
#include "msg.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void parseResponse(String &payload, float &temp, float &wind, int &pressure, int &humid, float &feel, int &uv)
{


    String json = payload;

    // Serial.println(json); // enable to debug

    StaticJsonDocument<128> filter;

    JsonObject filter_current = filter.createNestedObject("current");
    filter_current["temp_c"] = true;
    filter_current["wind_mph"] = true;
    filter_current["pressure_mb"] = true;
    filter_current["precip_in"] = true;
    filter_current["humidity"] = true;
    filter_current["feelslike_c"] = true;
    filter_current["uv"] = true;

    StaticJsonDocument<256> doc;

    // Deseriliaze and display error description if there is any
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, json, DeserializationOption::Filter(filter));

    if (error)
    {
        Serial.print("deserializeJson() failed: ");
        Serial.println(error.c_str());
        return;
    }

    JsonObject current = doc["current"];
    temp = current["temp_c"];          // 80
    wind = current["wind_mph"];        // 5.6
    pressure = current["pressure_mb"]; // 1005
    humid = current["humidity"];       // 93
    feel = current["feelslike_c"];     // 6.9
    uv = current["uv"];                // 1
}
```

together with its header file as below:

```
#ifndef MSG_H
#define MSG_H

void parseResponse(String &payload, float &temp, float &wind, int &pressure, int &humid, float &feel, int &uv);

#endif
```

I have included all the relevant libraries in the .cpp files. However, when I try to compile the code I get multiple errors such as

```
In file included from src/weatherapi.cpp:1:0:
include/weatherapi.h:4:17: error: variable or field 'getRequest' declared void
 void getRequest(String &payload);
                 ^
include/weatherapi.h:4:17: error: 'String' was not declared in this scope
include/weatherapi.h:4:25: error: 'payload' was not declared in this scope
 void getRequest(String &payload);
                         ^
Archiving .pio\build\lolin32\liba47\libPubSubClient.a
In file included from src/msg.cpp:1:0:
include/msg.h:4:20: error: variable or field 'parseResponse' declared void
 void parseResponse(String &payload, float &temp, float &wind, int &pressure, int &humid, float &feel, int &uv);
                    ^
include/msg.h:4:20: error: 'String' was not declared in this scope
include/msg.h:4:28: error: 'payload' was not declared in this scope
 void parseResponse(String &payload, float &temp, float &wind, int &pressure, int &humid, float &feel, int &uv);
                            ^
include/msg.h:4:37: error: expected primary-expression before 'float'
 void parseResponse(String &payload, float &temp, float &wind, int &pressure, int &humid, float &feel, int &uv);
                                     ^
include/msg.h:4:50: error: expected primary-expression before 'float'
 void parseResponse(String &payload, float &temp, float &wind, int &pressure, int &humid, float &feel, int &uv);
                                                  ^
include/msg.h:4:63: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 void parseResponse(String &payload, float &temp, float &wind, int &pressure, int &humid, float &feel, int &uv);
                                                               ^
include/msg.h:4:78: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 void parseResponse(String &payload, float &temp, float &wind, int &pressure, int &humid, float &feel, int &uv);
                                                                              ^
include/msg.h:4:90: error: expected primary-expression before 'float'
 void parseResponse(String &payload, float &temp, float &wind, int &pressure, int &humid, float &feel, int &uv);
                                                                                          ^
include/msg.h:4:103: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 void parseResponse(String &payload, float &temp, float &wind, int &pressure, int &humid, float &feel, int &uv);
```

The function parseResponse doesn't return anything so I don't know why it's complaining about being declared as void. Same is true for the function getRequest. Also, is there something wrong in the function prototype as I am passing references?

Edit: Here is the weatherapi.cpp & .h file

```
#include "weatherapi.h"
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

const char url[] = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

void getRequest(String &payload)
{

     HTTPClient getClient;

    getClient.begin(url);

   
    int httpCode = getClient.GET();

    //get response and check HTTP status code returned
    if (httpCode > 0)
    {
        payload = getClient.getString();
        Serial.print("HTTP Status: ");
        Serial.println(httpCode);
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
    }
   
    getClient.end();
}
```

weatherapi.h file

```
#ifndef WEATHERAPI_H
#define WEATHERAPI_H

void getRequest(String &payload);
#endif
```

Comment: Your problems start *before* the code you have shown us. Specifically in (or even before) weatherapi.h. It says it doesn't know what `String` is - did you include Arduino.h in there?

Comment: Yes I have included Arduino.h but still the same error :(. Please see updated post

Comment: Order is important.... Arduno.h must be included *before* it is used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C order is important. Everything is parsed sequentially, and header file inclusions are replaced literally with the header contents at compile time.

Things *must* be defined before they can be used, and that includes anything that is defined in the `Arudino.h` header file - that file *must* be included *before* anything that uses it - and of course that means that it must come before any headers that use things from `Arduino.h`

To be safer it's good to include `Arduino.h` in *every* file that uses anything from it so you don't run into these problems in future.

Comment: Included Arduino.h in all .cpp files and it compiles without error.  Though I omitted it only in places where I thought it wasn't needed at all but perhaps it was required somewhere.